# Cycle through an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, optimization, extension-methods

I built an extension method to cycle through all items of an `IEnumerable` starting at some index:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Circle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int startIndex)
{
    if (list != null)
    {
        List<T> firstList = new List<T>();
        using (var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator())
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (i < startIndex)
                {
                    firstList.Add(enumerator.Current);
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return enumerator.Current;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var first in firstList)
        {
            yield return first;
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

So when you do

```
Enumerable.Range(1,10).Circle(5);
```

The result is 6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5.

What I don't like is the use of the `firstList` variable. **Is there a way to do this with the enumerator only, without storing an intermediate result?**

**EDIT:**
I use an enumerator to iterate the enumerable not more than once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A shorter form of Trevor's answer (but essentially doing the same thing):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Circle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int startIndex)
{
    return list.Skip(startIndex).Concat(list.Take(startIndex));
}
```

This will still lazy evaluate just like Trevor's answer, because `Concat` lazily evaluates.

Further more, if you have written a method to *cycle* through an `IEnumerable`, why not call it `Cycle`?

Lastly, I'd actually recommend taking advantage of lazy evaluation to give you a more useful method. The one below will continue to cycle indefinitely, starting with an optional index:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Cycle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int index = 0)
{

    var count = list.Count();
    index = index % count;

    while(true)
    {
        yield return list.ElementAt(index);
        index = (index + 1) % count;
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
foreach(var num in Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Cycle(4).Take(30))
{
    Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
}
```

And this lets you specify just how many repeated items you want.

Comment: `list.ElementAt` will have terrible performance if the underlying collection doesn't support random access.  Your algorithm will be `O(n^2)` in that case.

Comment: Very true, but my review was intended to suggest alternative methods of structuring the entire method. The exact way of getting the element isn't important in my answer at all and could trivially be replaced.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's a bit shorter and it basically does the same thing. Your second method isn't useful in my use case (I really need one complete cycle without knowing the number of elements in advance), but I can imagine suitable use cases. I don't like that it requires a `Take` to come to an end though. (And I swapped two lines to make it work).

Comment: Haha, oops, looks like I copy-pasted those lines in the wrong order!

Answer (score 1):

The background, not mentioned in the question, was that I wanted this to work on `IQueryable`s from a database backend. Therefore, repeated execution of the input variable should be prevented and the best solution for this more limited case is:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Circle<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int startIndex)
{
    var localList = query.ToList();
    return localList.GetRange(startIndex, localList.Count - startIndex)
                    .Concat(localList.GetRange(0,startIndex));
}
```

When testing this with 10<sup>7</sup> integers, the statement `var localList = query.ToList();` took approx. 70% of the time. But `List.GetRange` is a highly efficient method, so all in all this is the winner.

Comment: A `.ToList()` in an extension method that takes `IEnumerable<T>` and returns `IEnumerable<T>` needs a  _darn_ good comment on it to explain exactly why the `.ToList()` is required.

Comment: @PaulSuart Well, obviously it is to prevent multiple execution of `list` which is a pretty standard pattern.

Comment: But if the `IEnumerable<T>` you pass in is very large, and/or expensive to obtain... this method simply does not scale.  For example, you can represent infinite collections with `IEnumerable` - this method would not work at all.

Comment: @PaulSuart My prime focus was on `IQueryable`s from a database which shouldn't be enumerated multiple times. Since that wasn't mentioned in the question my answer has a smaller usability scope than Nick's. Your comment made me aware of this. For that reason I'm marking the other answer as accepted.

Comment: That's all good.  I'd suggest a small improvement would be to make your method an extension for `IQueryable<T>` not `IEnumerable<T>` in that case.

Comment: @PaulSuart OK, good suggestion. Well, after all I think this Q&A looks better now than before your comments.

Comment: I think the method should take an `IQueryable<T>` but return an `IEnumerable<T>` as you've materialised the query's results inside the extension method.